# How to find a mean, mode, and variance of a distribution problem?

Tags: statistical-inference

I'm really not good in math, please bear with me. I searched and found some questions which are similar to this question. However, I cannot understand them.
I get doubt in this question for a day. It's quite easy but I don't know.

If I have 3 boxes, and I put tickets into them. For example, three boxes are put 1, 3, and 2 tickets respectively.

How can I find the average, variance, and mode of boxes?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: average, variance and mode from what? Tickets in a box?

Comment: Hi @Rcoster, I want to find the Average of boxes.

Comment: Are you sure? Because you have only 1 number (3 box), so, statistics don't make sense.

Comment: @Rcoster, what do you mean by 1 number? I have 3 boxes and in each box is put the tickets. For example, the first, second, and third has 1, 3, 2 tickets respectively.

Comment: So you want the average of tickets by box, not the average of box.

Comment: @Rcoster, huh probably yes. Actually, how different between the average of boxes and the average of tickets? and What is the result?

Comment: @Willy, you have strictly 3 boxes. Average of {3} is 3. Doing statistics doesn't make sense for boxes in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The average is just the sum of the number of tickets in each box and divide by the number of boxes:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x}}{n} = \frac{1+2+3}{3} = 2 = \mu$$

The variance is:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{(x-\mu)^2}}{n} = \frac{(-1)^2 + 0^2 + 1^2}{3} = 0.666$$

The mode is the value that occurs more times. When all values occur the exact same times, we have an amodal data (your case).

Comment: Actually, it's not what I want to find. I would like to find in the case of the average of boxes.
The good example for my case is that when we use the binomial distribution. We can get the number of success and failure in each time. For instance, we roll a dice 10 times. We can calculate the probability of six outcomes. The question is how can we find the average of the six values without using the theory np?